# Tomcat 6 Windows Server 64 Redirect Connector Fails

Tags: iis-6, tomcat6, isapi, windows-server-2003

So is there some problem with running the Tomcat connectors under a 64 bit windows OS?

Here's my configuration:

- Windows Server 2003 64 bit Intel Xeon
- Tomcat 6.0.26
- JVM 1.6.0 (64bit) ISAPI
- Redirect Connector 1.2.30.0 (64 bit)

Calling the IP address of the site with :8080 brings up the tomcat page so I know that's running and the examples all work so its obviously not having a problem with the JVM. Calling the site ip on port 80 however gives me error 324 - looking at the application log on windows shows "Could not load all ISAPI filters for site/service. Therefore startup aborted". The ISAPI filter page under the web site properties shows the status of this filter to be down with a red arrow.

The ISAPI filter name is jakarta and there is a corresponding virtual directory set up in the root of the site pointing to the same directory as the filter.  The jakarta web service extension is also pointing to the required dll (c:\program files\apache software foundation\jakarta isapi redirector\bin\isapi_redirect.dll).

Incidentally, this same problem occurs when trying to use Tomcat 5.5. I've also tried swapping out various redirect versions. It's really odd because I got it to work once with a version of the redirector that came with Plesk but I've since uninstalled everything to do with plesk and even trying to use the plesk-compiled dll doesn't work now.

I am pulling my hair out on this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In this case it seems to work best if you use a 32 bit version of the redirect dll, but you have to coax Windows 64 into running the dll by using the following script at a command prompt:

```
cscript %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
```

I hope this is useful to someone else.